# Give pages an keyword and list other pages with this keyword on the current page

Tags: wiki, wiki-pages, confluence

we have worked with Confluence so far now we switched to Office 365 and SharePoint. So we want to use SharePoint pages just like Confluence as a Wiki. In order to build a good wiki we have to link content and do this as automatically and uncomplicated as possible.

At Confluence you can give pages a tag.  Using the macro 'Content by keyword' you can list other pages on the current page which have the same tag.

Is there such a greate thing also in SharePoint? We will hope so!